# why does this StrReplace operation not work with string sent in via A_Args[1]?

Tags: autohotkey

```
ObjectsList := ["In","Out", "Dogs"]
In     := 50
Out    := 100
Dogs   := 5

For each, Obj in ObjectsList
    RawArgs := StrReplace(A_Args[1], "$" Obj, %Obj%)

msgbox, % RawArgs
```

If I run the above code as a script via command line (`.\somepath\AHKScript.ahk '$In-5,$Out-50'`). I am expecting, `RawArgs` to be `50-5,100-50` but instead I get `$In-5,$Out-50`.

While the following code I get what I am expecting to get, which is `50-5,100-50` :

```
RawArgs    := "$In-5,$Out-50" 
ObjectsList := ["In","Out", "Dogs"]
In     := 50
Out    := 100
Dogs   := 5

For each, Obj in ObjectsList
    RawArgs := StrReplace(RawArgs, "$" Obj, %obj%)

OutputDebug, % RawArgs
```

I tried getting to the bottom of this but to no avail. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're just reassigning to `RawArgs` every time. You do indeed replace successfully each time, but you just immediately overwrite and discard the result during the next cycle of the for-loop. And because your last search is for "Dogs", which doesn't exist, nothing gets replaced and you're left with the original string.

Also, you really should forget about dynamic variables. It's just super legacy.

Here's one way you could do your script:

```
output := A_Args[1]

ObjectsList := { "In": 50
               , "Out": 100
               , "Dogs": 5 }


for key, value in ObjectsList
    output := StrReplace(output, "$" key, value)

MsgBox, % output
```

Although a regex approach could be more suitable.

Comment: I am just grapling with anything that will work lol and sure enough your solution is one more step forward. Thansk for the answer and the alternative solution